# UEFI does not see bootable partition

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I installed kubuntu on my laptop recently. It's the only system on laptop. Today I was working on it, when it suddenly freezed. I did hard reboot and my system didn't found any OS on my SSD. Currently I am using usb flash drive. What should i do to restore my linux?
In case this wiil give any useful information:

```
kubuntu@kubuntu:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0    7:0    0   2.8G  1 loop /rofs
loop1    7:1    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop2    7:2    0  63.3M  1 loop /snap/core20/1822
loop3    7:3    0  91.7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop4    7:4    0 240.6M  1 loop /snap/firefox/2356
loop5    7:5    0 346.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/119
loop6    7:6    0  49.8M  1 loop /snap/snapd/18357
sda      8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk 
sdb      8:16   1  28.9G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   1   4.7G  0 part /cdrom
├─sdb2   8:18   1   4.9M  0 part 
├─sdb3   8:19   1   300K  0 part 
└─sdb4   8:20   1  24.2G  0 part /var/crash
                                 /var/log
```

Thanks for help!
P.S. Sorry for my bad english